# Vtiger. Change query limit

Tags: vtiger

In vtiger wiki [written](https://wiki.vtiger.com/index.php/Webservices_tutorials#Queries):

> Query always limits its output to 100 records, client application can use limit operator to get different records.

This query does not work:

```
doQuery("select * from Leads limit='200';")
```

How to specify the operator in a query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "limit" clause only works if the number given is lower than 100. You can't get more records than 100 using "limit" with 1 request.

**To get more than 100 records from vTiger services you need to make various request using the "offset" in the "limit" clause.**

Comment: I found the [solution](https://github.com/gizur/gizurcloud/wiki/System_Documentation%23Design%23lib%23vTiger) for setting a limit on the server. it is correct?

Answer (score 0):

If you **really** read the Wiki documentation, you'd see that you need to use:

```
select * 
from Leads 
limit 200;
```

Stop using unnecessary single quotes (`'200'`) - the `limit` expects a numerical value, there's absolutely no point in converting that to a string (by using single quotes) .....

and drop the equal sign, too - it's not shown in the docs anywhere .....

Comment: thanks for the answer. I tried different options. a variant spelling of the same does not work. `doQuery("select * from Leads limit 200;")`